# user register form in the django not getting register

Tags: python, django

I am trying to register the user of the django website but it was not getting register
I am posting the code please help me

this is the code of the views.py where I get the input

```
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect

# Create your views here.
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import User_Main

def become_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request , user)
            user_main = User_Main.objects.create(name = user.username, created_by=user)
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()


    return render(request, 'user_of_ecommerce/become_user.html' ,{'form':form})
```

code of urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('become-user/' , views.become_user , name="become_user")
]
```

and here is the code of the form

```
    {% extends "core_of_ecommerce/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <form action="." method="post" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <div>
            <button>sbmot</button>
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

another URLs.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('' ,views.home, name='home')
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class User_Main(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='user_name')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

when I click on the button after entering all the details it refreshes me to the same page I hope you can help me
and I even checked from the admin panel It doesn't register

Comment: if you any more information then please just comment below

Comment: form action = "." ?

Comment: sir i used it to remain on same page should I have to change it or remove it I am just learning django please help

Comment: try removing that

Comment: sir not even working right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your template are causing this ,because you did not submit correctly ,chagge the button submit

```
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <div>
         <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </div>
</form>
```

as for action it is better that you create a url named login ,that handle a login view

**Update**

ok let's do like this ,replace your register view with this,

```
    def become_user(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                return redirect('home')

        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()

        return render(request, 'user_of_ecommerce/become_user.html' ,{'form':form})
```

and verify that the user is acually saved (in  you admin page), then we worry about logging in.

once the save is working, modify you view like this:

```
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login


    def become_user(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                user = authenticate(username=cd['username'], password=cd['password1'])    #new line
                login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend') #new line
                return redirect('home')

        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()

        return render(request, 'user_of_ecommerce/become_user.html' ,{'form':form})
```

Comment: but sir user is not even getting register then how can I login using it

Comment: did you import redirect? from django.shortcuts import redirect,

Comment: sir can i send you the rar file of the code with drive link

Answer (score 0):

```
def become_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request , user)
            user_main = User_Main.objects.create(name = user.username, created_by=user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'user_of_ecommerce/become_user.html' ,{'form':form})
```